# Angular Material Button and RxJS fromEvent function - there is no nativeElement property but just _nativeElement property

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have an Angular component and in its template I have placed an Angular Material button, i.e. something like `<button #myButton mat-button></button>`.

Now what I want to do is to get hold of this button in my code, generate an Observable that emits when the button is clicked and happily do whatever I need to do with such Observable.

First thing: I get hold of the button using `@ViewChild` with the following code

```
@ViewChild('myButton') myButton: MatButton;
```

I specify the type of the variable as `MatButton` since it is actually of that type.

And eventually my problem. I would like to use my usual approach, i.e. use `fromEvent(this.myButton.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click')`in the `ngAfterViewInit` method. Unfortunately I get an error `Invalid event target`. Digging a bit I find that `MatButton` does not have a property `elementRef` but it has a property named `_elementRef`. From the leading underscore this sounds like a private property, but I did not find any better way to create an Observable starting from a `MatButton` directive and using `fromEvent` function of RxJS.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the `ElementRef` of the button with the `read` option of `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild("myButton", { read: ElementRef }) myButtonRef: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.myButtonRef.nativeElement);
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-button-eg-xpcng2?file=app/button-types-example.ts) for a demo and [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/) for more info about `ViewChild`.

Comment: note that in ng8 ViewChild requires the static option to be set as well `@ViewChild('myButton', {read: ElementRef, static: false})`.

Answer (score 0):

Some (not sure if all) Angular Material components expose EventEmitter observables to which you can subscribe directly, without using `fromEvent`.

For example, for the `MatSlideToggle` component, you could write:

```
@ViewChild('myToggle', { static: true }) myToggle: MatSlideToggle;
```

and then in your `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
this.myToggle.change.subscribe((event: MatSlideToggleChange) => {
    ...
})
```

I assume the click event in your example is also exposed by MatButton, but I didn't try it.